# Why say 'chai tea'?

Tags: word-usage

The Hindi word for tea (the drink) is *chai*. In India, this is the primary kind of tea (also, Hindi isn’t spoken throughout India); so, IndE speakers say “I’ll have some tea” rather than “I'll have some chai”.

The drink has become popular in the West, and is referred to as [chai](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/chai) to disambiguate it from tea prepared any other way.

However, I’ve been hearing the phrase *chai tea* increasingly often. Isn’t it redundant? To me, it’s like saying *cappuccino coffee*.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chai+tea&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchai%20tea%3B%2Cc0) shows that it’s a recent phrase, and is growing in usage.

Hence my question: is it correct to say *chai tea* in BrE/AmE, or should we simply say *chai*?

**EDIT**: I don't want the answer to be opinion-based. I'm looking for a source which explains why this usage is right or wrong.

Comment: [***Chai** is made using different formulas, depending on the region where it is being consumed, but there are a number of standard ingredients: **black tea, ginger, cardamom, cinnamon, fennel, clove** and **black pepper***.](http://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-5825/Why-Everyone-Should-Drink-Chai-Tea.html) I'll stick to my standard ***cuppa cha*** - optionally with an ***r***, but not an ***i***.

Comment: *Chai tea* exists for the exact same reason, and is just as correct, as *pin number* and *atm machine*. Meaning to say: perfectly correct, and perfectly reasonable, and ubiquitous in absolutely all languages at absolutely all times. That is how our brain works.

Comment: 'Chai tea' sounds redundant to you, because you're used to 'chai' being a synonym for 'tea'. The word 'chai' is relatively new outside of India, doesn't sound like anything else, and at the very best sounds like a very specific kind of tea (vaguely tea with some Indian-like spices, like maybe cinnamon). Some non-IndE speakers will say just 'chai' but others, not aware that  it means tea, will feel the need to specify 'tea of the chai variety'. [Why do people say 'The La Brea Tarpits'? when 'La Brea' means 'the tar'?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Other_forms). English isn't Spanish.

Comment: @Mitch: It's a pleonasm. I get it now. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction It's a pleonasm to you. To many AmE/BrE speakers, it is not ('chai' being the kind of spice rather than the tea)

Comment: Note that *chai* is originally a *Chinese* word for tea, exported (along with the beverage) to much of Asia. So this phrase is not just redundant, but non-descriptive to much of the world's population, who put neither milk nor spices in their chai/tea.

Comment: Chai is also used in Arabic, Turkish, and Persian, among other languages.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This question already has an accepted answer. You should only add another answer if you can improve on it. Your post is not wrong, but it is inappropriate for the question and answer model used on StackExchange.

Comment: I have absolutely heard people say _cappuccino coffee_, which does make more sense – after all, neither Capuchin monks nor their hoods is a type of coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pleonasm to me, an InE speaker.

> Other phrases that seem redundant because the foreign word means the
>   same thing as the English word:
>
> •Gobi desert (Gobi means "desert" in Mongolian.)
>
> •Naan bread (Naan is a type of bread in many countries.)
>
> **Chai** means "tea" in Hindi, so when we order "chai tea," we're asking for "**tea tea**," at least that's what it sounds like to
>   someone from India

To non InE speakers, "chai" in chai-tea is a kind of spice rather than the tea.

> [In America](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/chai-tea-redundant) the phrase chai tea has come to mean the particular
>   kind of tea made in the Indian style. (What Americans call chai tea
>   would be more accurately called masala chai ― masala is the mix of
>   spices used to flavor the chai.)

Ref- [Is "Chai Tea" Redundant](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/chai-tea-redundant)?

Comment: Upvoting purely because I don't have to explain my question to you, or point out that you have to add resources.

Answer (score 4):

I was always under the impression that chai tea referred to a certain blend of tea, usually lightly spiced.

> [Masala Chai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masala_chai)

As opposed to the variety that would usually be drunk in Britain (I can't speak for the US) with milk - and sugar for the heathens - referred to simply as 'Tea'.

> [English Breakfast Tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_breakfast_tea)

So while you are correct in stating that 'chai' does indeed mean 'tea' in BrE general, everyday use the two are known as referring to specific types of tea.

Answer (score 3):

Many American English speakers understand *chai* to refer to a way of preparing tea, and for them it is natural to use *chai* adjectivally.  If you understand *chai* to mean "tea prepared in the Indian manner" then *chai tea* can strike your ear as pleonastic.

Answer (score 2):

> My opinion: Chai (tea) is nothing but rechristening of the Indian chai for the export market under the name of **[chai tea](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VVxlfDHGTFYC&pg=PA151&dq=chai%20tea%20in%20india&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B9tdVdXVG5S0uQSFm4OQCA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=chai%20tea%20in%20india&f=false).**

- The "chai tea" usage would be understood but frowned upon in India.

Similar usage-

Numerous United States coffee houses use the term **chai latte or chai tea latte** for their version to indicate that the steamed milk of a regular latte is mixed with a spiced tea concentrate instead of espresso. ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masala_chai))

Comment: Good answers do not start with "my opinion". I'm looking for facts.

Comment: I don't understand why people keep telling me HOW it is used. I'm aware of that, hence the question. Which is: WHY is it used that way.

Comment: @Area51 if you are looking for facts, why ask a question that predisposes that one particular usage is "right" and another is "wrong," an assertion that has no factual basis

Comment: @Pazzo: I can't believe how you guys still don't get it. `chai` is right. `chai tea` is either right or wrong. Nowhere have I said that only one of the two can be right.

Comment: *Chai tea* does not have to be either right or wrong. Different people have different attitudes about **usage**. A perfectly good usage that breaks no grammatical rules is wrong only to Usage Nazis.

Answer (score 0):

English speakers do not rely on foreign word meanings. The Arabic word for (great) desert is "Sahara." So "Sahara Desert" could be thought of as a similar tautology to "Chai tea."

SAT stands for Scholastic Aptitude Test. This doesn't stop many people from saying *SAT Test.*

Comment: This answer doesn't really point out anything the questioner didn't already know. You could make the answer considerably more useful to the questioner (and to others reading it) if you also addressed the obvious follow-up question: "Why do people want to say it?"